# Trying to use javaScript to make the second image shows instead of the first

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show the next image by just adding the `style: display(none)` but it is not working at all

```html
<script>
  function displayBanner() {
    var count = 1;
    if (count == 1) {
      document.getElementById("banner_img3").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  displayBanner();
</script>
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <div id="banner">
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img1"></div>
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img2"></div>
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: ```style:display: none;``` used to hide the contents not to show?

Comment: Your element does not exist when you execute the script before the element. Move the script to after the elements or move displayBanner into a load event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element does not exist when you execute the script before the element. Move the script to after the elements or move displayBanner into a load event

I assume you want to rotate the images

```js
var count = 0, max;
function displayBanner() {
  document.getElementById("banner_img"+count).style.display = "none";
  count++
  if (count === max ) count = 0
  document.getElementById("banner_img"+count).style.display = "block";
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  max = document.querySelectorAll(".banner_img").length;
  document.getElementById("banner_img0").style.display = "block";
  setInterval(displayBanner, 3000);
})
```

```css
.banner_img { display:none; text-align:center }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <div id="banner">
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img0"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" /><br/>Image 1</div>
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-2.jpg" /><br/>Image 2</div>
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" /><br/>Image 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

your div didn't have any source add a source using `<img src=""></img>` for the div try below code for that

```
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <div id="banner">
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img1"><img src="http://templatesforcv.com/wp-content/uploads/06.jpg" ></div>
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img2"><img src="http://templatesforcv.com/wp-content/uploads/06.jpg"></div>
      <div class="banner_img" id="banner_img3"><img src="http://templatesforcv.com/wp-content/uploads/06.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

window.onload=displayBanner();

function displayBanner() {
  var count = 1;
  if (count == 1) {
    document.getElementById("banner_img3").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

working demo:https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/yh2esp1c/21/